# Elasticsearch Multiple indice wilcard querystring not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-5

In the [Current [5.0] elasticsearch doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html) it was said that

> All multi indices API support the following url query string :
> ***ignore_unavailable*** and  ***allow_no_indices***

I delete all exiting indice and try to create a new one with mapping

```
curl -XDELETE "http://elastic:elastic@127.0.0.1:9200/mail-*?pretty=true"
curl -XPUT "http://elastic:elastic@127.0.0.1:9200/mail-*?ignore_unavailable=true&pretty=true" -d '   {
"mappings": {
  "ex": {
    "properties": {
      ...
```

I got this error :

**"request [/mail-*] contains unrecognized parameter: [ignore_unavailable]"**

i need to create this mapping because index are created by logstash with a new index every day  index => "mail-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"

if i remove the wilcard in indice name it works !

why i need to do this beacause i use the geoip filter in logstash but the geoip.location is not in the type "geo_point" and kibana tile map doesnt work without this

Comment: How this works is that you need to specify an index template for an index `mail-*` and when Logstash sends an event for an index like that one ES will use that template for creating it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-templates.html

Comment: And the output you get is normal. The index you create has to have a name and wildcards are not permitted. Wildcards can be used in the indices templates, as I mentioned earlier.